# My mouse’s right click act as back button in my Android TV browser. How do I disable it?

Tags: applications, 9.0-pie, android-tv

A USB mouse plugged into my Android Tv, and when I browse my website and right click on my mouse by default it work as a back button and website goes to previous page.

I want to remove this functionality i.e right button click should not work as a back button. Or at-least when I click the right button it should not take me back to the previous page. If there's any solution it will be helpful.